# how to hide myself while web scraping by html-agility-pack

Tags: asp.net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrap content from some webpages of a site. I tried html-agility-pack with c#, which is doing good in scraping html.Here I need to go through some numbers of pages  while scraping. Now my question is how can I hide my self as webscraper? As I do not want other side come to know that i am scraping their content.Please Let me know if there is any way that can help me.Looking forward for your responses.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a tor proxy:

[Tor Project](https://www.torproject.org/)

You can reset the proxy after every page or after every site. Keep in mind that some sites look for certain patterns and can tell your scraping them. With html agility pack the web is one big data repository, just make sure your not use someone else's data in a way that would get you in trouble.